# jQuery inArray with Hashtable

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable

I'm using a hash table and I'm trying to check for object existence. However I haven't been successful in figuring out how to do this. Could someone help guide me with this. Thanks.

current code.

When clientId equals field id and has item id return true, else add to saved_tokens.

```
var saved_tokens = {}; 

if ($.inArray(item.id, saved_tokens) == -1) { 
    saved_tokens.push[clientId] = item.id;
}
```

Comment: Note that you can never call functions without parens. Currently you're setting a property on the `.push` function.

Comment: Are you trying to check if the key `clientId` already exists in the object, or if the value `item.id` already exists?

Comment: I have multiple clientId's that could share the same items. I need to test the clientId to see if it contains an Item, if not add it to the the saved_toekens with the clientId.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use jQuery for that. Use pure JavaScript:

```
if (!saved_tokens.hasOwnProperty(clientId)) { // If clientId is not in the hash
    saved_tokens[clientId] = item.id;
}
```

`.push` is an array method. A `{}` creates an object. Since this object is not an array, it doesn't have any array methods.

Comment: Does this also prevent duplicate item.id's from being added to the hash?

Comment: @George No. You have two options: 1) Also maintain a hashtable for the `item.id`, or 2) Loop through all `saved_tokens`, and check whether the value is (not) equal to `item.id`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use 'typeof'.

```
var saved_tokens = {}; 

if (typeof(saved_tokens[clientId]) == 'undefined') { 
    saved_tokens[clientId] = item.id;
}
```

Comment: Noting that this doesn't distinguish between whether `clientId` exists as a key in the object with the value `undefined` or if `clientId` doesn't exist as a key at all. `if (clientId in saved_tokens)` tests if it has been defined as a key (with any value).

Comment: @nnnnnn 

I dont get your comment. Do you mean to say that if clietId having value 'undefined' and clientId doesnt exits both will be true with typeof ?

Comment: Yes. If `saved_tokens` has a key `clientId` but the value associated with that key is `undefined` then `typeof` will return `"undefined"` just as it also would if `saved_tokens` does not have a key `clientId` at all. If you need to distinguish between those two possibilities then use `if (clientId in saved_tokens)`, or if you need to know if the property is directly set on the object (and not inherited through the prototype chain) use `saved_tokens.hasOwnProperty(clientId)`

Comment: @nnnnnn 

May be I am getting your answer wrong but this works,

http://jsbin.com/ayocin/2/edit

Comment: Sorry, your link didn't work for me (might be an IE problem). I'm not saying `typeof` won't work (it does!), I'm saying it doesn't distinguish between the two cases that might cause the expression `saved_tokens[clientId]` to be undefined - which for some purposes doesn't matter.

Comment: jsbin not working in ie7.    
`var a = {
      'b' : 'undefined' 
    }
    
    if(typeof(a['b']) == 'undefined'){
      a['b'] = 'hello';
    }
    
    alert(a['b']); 
    // alerts undefined`

Comment: You're not setting the `b` property to be undefined, you're setting it to the string `"undefined"`.